# Second page AngularJS function not working in ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have two pages. In first page using controller1. and second page using controller2. I have include second page in first page.

The second page function are not wokring.

In first Page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("FirstCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    });
    </script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <div ng-include="'second.html'">
        </div>
</div>
```

In second page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
     app.controller("SecondCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

         $scope.Save = function () {
             alert("Hai");
         };
     });
    </script>

<div  ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
<input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="Save()" />
</div>
```

$scope.Save not working.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo sample link](http://plnkr.co/edit/IhY0nQUXZ7KS8XA5ni3c?p=preview)

In your code `<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">` in this line your using caps M -- MyApp u should use myApp and both script try to create module again first file need to create in second need to call.